# Orthographe de « artefact »

Tags: orthographe, réforme-orthographique-1991

Selon l'orthographe rectifiée il faut écrire *artéfact* au lieu de  *artefact*.

Quelle règle dicte l'introduction de l'accent aigu ?
Pourquoi les correcteurs de texte ne reconnaissent que la forme traditionnelle ?

Comment: J'ai un correcteur de texte qui reconnait la forme nouvelle seulement (réforme 1990).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Quelle règle dicte l'introduction de l'accent aigu ?

La mise en conformité de l'orthographe de mots d'origine étrangère avec leur prononciation usuelle, comme avec *di**é**sel* ou *pizz**é**ria*.

> Pourquoi les correcteurs de texte ne reconnaissent que la forme traditionnelle ?

L'inertie sans doute...